# Does anyone have any hard ciphers to be cracked for fun?

Tags: classical-cipher

The title says it all. Do you have any ciphers or encoded messages that you could post as a brainteaser?

Thanks!

Comment: We get a lot of off topic "please crack this cipher for me" here. So if you want to have a crack at those be our guest. And there are plenty of resources online such as the https://cryptopals.com/ challenge. If you follow cryptography II on Coursera then you get to perform a padding oracle attack, pretty nifty.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure anyone here has a sense of humour.  But in case they do:-

1. Obviously [Kryptos](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/01/29/climate/kryptos-sculpture-final-clue.html), CIA headquarters, Langley.
2. Less obviously, [this](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-20749632) sad one time pad message, Surrey, England (also proving that OTPs did exist and were useful).

Good luck, and please post your answers here :-(

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Who to accept?! Wish it were possible to accept both of your answers!

Comment: Haha, yes, I see why the :-(

Answer (score 1):

try this one [crackthehash2](https://tryhackme.com/room/crackthehashlevel2), and share your results :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!